# gem installed but 'rails' commands don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

when I run any rails command like `rails s` I get the following error:

Could not find diff-lcs-1.1.2 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.

However, I already installed diff-lcs.

> bundle show diff-lcs
>   /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.2

I also see diff-lcs when I do a `gem list` command

My GEM_HOME is /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1

For reference, here's the contents of my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

And the output of `which rails` is `/usr/bin/rails`

Comment: Just for giggles, can you post the output of `which rails`?

Comment: The output of which rails is /usr/bin/rails

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails 3, edit 'Gemfile' in the root of your rails app such that it contains

```
gem 'diff-lcs'
```

Then run 'bundle install' from the root of your rails app.

Comment: I am using rails 3.  I tried that and getting same exact error when I run any rails command.

Answer (score 0):

Type "gem env" on your terminal. Check the executable path. Verify that it's set correctly.

Comment: > gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin10]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/ben/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000

Comment: is /opt/local/bin set in your $PATH? Try running rails commmands by going into that directory e.g. cd /opt/local/bin --> ./rails

Comment: echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I had the same problem (though with Apache and Phusion, but the solution could quite easily be the same). It turns out that though I set the `GEM_PATH` in my .bashrc, the server evidently doesn't get the bash environment. I fixed it following the advice [here](http://iceboundflame.com/2010/12/setting-gem_home-on-phusion-passenger-3), in particular creating the  `config/setup_load_paths.rb` file and adding the following line:

```
ENV['GEM_HOME']='/path/to/my/gems'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

Still haven't found an ideal solution, but if you delete the 'spring' gem from your gemfile, you should at least get things up and running again.