# rails install broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just installed ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.9 on my windows dev machine and created an app with

```
rails new railstest
cd railstest
bundle install
rails server

script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
            from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

i don't understand what caused this error.  can anyone help me to understand what is happening?  i tried to do the require from irb and was successfull.  do i need to reinstall rails?  i tried googling for an answer and found this post

[error-when-trying-to-start-server-after-upgrading-to-rails-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042471/error-when-trying-to-start-server-after-upgrading-to-rails-3)

[gem-installed-but-rails-commands-dont-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948130/gem-installed-but-rails-commands-dont-work)

Comment: I have found the file `commands.rb` in the gem railties. Don't know why that is not visible. Have you tried to insert into your `rails.rb` file before the require statement the line: `p $:`? This should output the current load-path, perhaps there is something broken.

Comment: please copy-paste "bundle show" output here

Comment: here is the output from p $: from script/rails ["C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i386-msvcrt", "C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i386-msvcrt", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "C:/92/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32"]

Comment: `>bundle show` `Gems included by the bundle
  * bundler (1.0.15)`

Comment: That seems to show that only bundler is installed, not the necessary gems for driving rails.

Answer (score 2):

the only way is reinstall gems and bundle reinitialization

1. gem uninstall bundler # all versions
2. gem install bundler
3. rm Gemfile.lock
4. bundle install

Comment: Ok thank you very much i managed to fix the problem with # remove user-specific gems and git repos
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/

Comment: ok, that's really good solution to remove any system and user-specific gems, then use bundler-related only.